# How can a background Python process not simply monitor but capture shortkeys?

Tags: python, events, ubuntu, key, x11

I want to have a little Python program run in the background monitoring keystrokes. When it detects a certain shortkey, I want it to capture it (i.e. not allow it to propagate to a focussed application) and do something corresponding to that shortkey.

To be specific, I want this program to watch for certain key combinations and then run a little script that is to snap windows around according to the shortkeys. Let's say it's a terminal window that I want to snap to the side of the screen. Key here is that I do not want the shortkey to propagate to the terminal; I want the program to *capture* it, not simply monitor it.

How could this be done on Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you might have some code you've already tried it with?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You need to be familiar with the concept of key grab. You establish a passive grab on a key combination and it becomes a hotkey. When the user presses that key combination, it is delivered to the grabbing window instead of the current focus window. [Here](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/184.html) is an easy example. The centerpiece of this code is `root.grab_key`. Bear in mind is better to translate your keysyms to keycodes rather than to hard-code keycodes as the example does.